# How to convert JsonResult to ClosedXml?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable, closedxml, jsonresult

I have a dataset in a JSON-format. But how can I write this to a ClosedXML-format?

dataSet.Data { total = "123456", data = Count = 11, model '{\fields":{"DocumentId":{"title""...

```
    private void SetWorkbook(IXLWorkbook workbook, JsonResult dataSet)
    {
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Export");

        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataSet.Data, (typeof(DataTable)));
        ....
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PropertyInfo and Dictionary you can catch the JSON-data.

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> GetDataSet(object dataSet)
    {
        Type type = dataSet.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Name == "data")
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dynamic data = property.GetValue(dataSet);
                foreach (var rows in data)
                {
                    foreach (var row in rows)
                    {
                        string value = string.Empty;
                        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(row.Key))
                            value = dictionary[row.Key] + "," + row.Value;
                        else
                            value = row.Value;

                        dictionary[row.Key] = value;
                    }
                }

                return dictionary;
            }
        }

        return new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
```